# Where does email to Facebook test users go?

Tags: facebook, testing

I'm developing an app with Facebook connect.  I've created some test users using the API.  Now I want to send email to the user when they do certain actions.  The test users all have email addresses, but I'm not sure they're valid, nor where I would check the mail sent.

So where would it go if I sent email to a Facebook test user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not a valid email then it won't go anywhere.  Just like when you send a regular email to an invalid address.  I'm not sure but you might bet a bounce back notification or something.

Have you considered just sending them a Facebook message?

Comment: No, I hadn't thought of sending a Facebook message.  Unfortunately, my client has considered it and wants email only.